# Getting Data from two different Streams in Kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to make a Kinesis Consumer Client. To work on it I went through the Developer Guide of Kinesis and AWS Document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-java.html.

I was wondering is It possible to get Data from two different Streams and process it accordingly.

Say I have two different Streams `stream1` and `stream2` .

Is it possible to get Data from both stream and process individually ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not? Do get_records from both streams.

If your streams only have a single shard each, you will also see all the events, as it is recommended to process each shard with a single worker, but if your logic is somehow to join events from different sources/streams, you can implement it with a single worker reading from both streams.

Note that if you have streams with multiple shards, each one of your workers will see only a part of the events. You can have the following options:

- Both streams have a single shard each - in this case you can read with a single worker from bout streams and see all events from both streams. You can add timestamps or other keys to allow you to "join" these events in the worker.
- One stream (*stream1*) with one shard and the second streams (*stream2*) with multiple shards - in this case you can read from *stream1* from all your workers, that will also process single shard from the *stream2* each. Each one of your workers will see all the events of *stream1* and its share of events of *stream2*. Note that you have a [limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html) of the speed that you can read the events from *stream1* with the single shard (2MB/second or 5 reads/second), and if you have many shards in *stream2*, this can be a real limit.
- Both streams can have multiple shards - in this case it will be more complex for you to ensure that you are able to "join" these events, as you need to sync both the writes and the reads to these streams. You can also read from all shards of both streams with a single worker, but this is not a good practice as it is limiting your ability to scale since you don't have a distributed system anymore. Another option is to use the same [*partition_key*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/key-concepts.html#partition-key) in both streams, and have the same number of shards and partition definition for both streams, and verify that you are reading from the "right" shard from each stream in each of your workers, and that you are doing it correctly every time one of your workers is failing and restarting, which might be a bit complex.

Another option that you can consider is to write both types of events in a single stream, again using the same *partition_key*, and then filter them on the reader side if you need to process them differently (for example, to write them to different log files in S3).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. After Thinking too much I think If anyhow I can send data for both streams using only a single stream and In processRecords step I will segregate them, Isn't it a good idea ?

Comment: Yes. This is a simpler and scalable solution.